# How to change timezone of date and strtotime function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, timezone, strtotime

I have changed timezone with 'Asia/Kolkata' in app.php

```
 Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',`
```

Now I trying to calculation between two time than output giving +5:30 time

how to fix this issue?

example:-

```
$inTime = "10:08:00";
$outTime = "10:08:00";
$spentTime = strtotime($outTime) - strtotime($inTime);
echo "<pre>";
print_r("out time = ".$outTime);
echo "<br>";
print_r("in time = ".$inTime);
echo "<br>";
print_r("spent time = ".$spentTime);
                
$spentTime = **date('H:i:s', $spentTime)**;
echo "<br>";
print_r("spent time format = ".$spentTime);
die;
```

Output:-

```
 out time = 10:08:00
 in time = 10:08:00
 spent time = 0
 spent time format = 05:30:00
```

I expecting "spent time format" given = 00:00:00

What can we do so that we can achieve this?

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: date() is not suitable to format time portion alone.. it's not even a format function. What you do is, you express the timestamp 0 which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Your timezone is 5:30 ahead of UTC, that's why the 0 results in 5:30

Comment: Thanks, @HonkderHase, for quick reply. So which function is suitable for time portion alone?

Comment: DateInterval is intended to express periods of time

Answer (score 0):

try to use Carbon in your prject.

```
$inTime = Carbon::parse('10:08:00', 'Asia/Kolkata');
$outTime = Carbon::parse('10:08:00', 'Asia/Taipei');
//You can replace diffInSeconds with other diff methods. 
$spentTime = $outTime->diff($inTime)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```